# django-admin model with overriden change_form.html missing context

Tags: templates, django-admin, customization

I have the following 3 models, each of which has a 1-many relationship with it's children

```
* Experiment
  * Site (lab, schools, etc.)
     * Participants
```

Since a Site might have hundreds of participants, I've overridden it's models change_form.html, where I've added a 'bulk create' form in the 'after_field_sets' block.

Here's my my-project/templates/admin/my-app/site/change_form.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}

{% block after_field_sets %}
{{ block.super }}
<h3>Bulk Create Participants</h3>
 <form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create"/>
    <label>First uid (inclusive) <input type="text" name="firstUid"/></label>
    <label>Last uid (inclusive) <input type="text" name="lastUid"/></label>
    <label>Condition Order<input type="text" name="conditionOrder"/></label>
  </form>
<hr/>

{% endblock %}
```

If I do nothing else, everything gets displayed properly, however without a custom view, I don't have any way of processing the custom form. When I add a `get_urls()` and a custom view to my `SiteAdmin`, which should allow me to process the custom form, only the 'after_field_sets' block is displayed.

Here's my Site ModelAdmin:

```
class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['experiment', 'name', 'description']
    readonly_fields = ['experiment']
    inlines = [ParticipantInline]

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(SiteAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r"^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$", self.admin_site.admin_view(self.my_view,
                                                                 cacheable=True)),
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        context = dict(
            self.admin_site.each_context(request),
             opts = Site._meta,
             change = True,
             is_popup=False,
             save_as=False,
             has_delete_permission=False,
             has_add_permission=False,
             has_change_permission=False
        )
        if request.method == 'POST':
            action = request.POST["action"]
            firstUID = request.POST["firstUid"]
            lastUID = request.POST["lastUid"]
            if "create" == action:
              for uid in range(firstUID, lastUID+1):
                 Participant.objects.create(site=site, uid=uid)
        return TemplateResponse(request, "admin/experimentAdmin/site/change_form.html", context)
```

Is there more information I need to pass to the context to get the entire form to display?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that a better way to do this was to **not** to override the change_form.html template, but rather create a `ModelForm` for my Site model, where I defined some extra fields (not part of the actual model), set required=False on these fields, added them to the ModelAdmin's fieldset, and handled the optional extra form fields in my `SiteAdmin::save_model()`

```
class SiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_uid = forms.IntegerField(label='First UID', required=False)
    last_uid = forms.IntegerField(label='Last UID', required=False)
    conditions_order = forms.CharField(label='Conditions Order', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ("name", "description",
                  "first_uid", "last_uid", "conditions_order")


class SiteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SiteForm
    inlines = [ParticipantInline]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
                "fields": ("name", "description")
         }),
        ("Bulk Create Participants", {
                "fields": ("first_uid", "last_uid",
                           "conditions_order")
         })
    )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
       # deal with optional fields if present
       ...
       obj.save()
```